# Fullcalendar set height in mobile version

Tags: css, angular, fullcalendar

i'm using fullcalendar in an angular project. My problem is: how could i change the height of the calendar when i use a phone?
I've tried contentHeight, but do not work (i want to the change height when i change the resolution).
That is the variable calendarOptions:

```
public calendarOptions: any = {
    eventLimit: true,
    contentHeight: () => {
        if (screen.height < 577) {
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                contentHeight: 600
            });
        } else {
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                contentHeight: 'auto'
            });
        }
    },
    timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
    monthNames: [
        'Gennaio',
        'Febbraio',
        'Marzo',
        'Aprile',
        'Maggio',
        'Giugno',
        'Luglio',
        'Agosto',
        'Settembre',
        'Ottobre',
        'Novembre',
        'Dicembre',
    ],
    showNonCurrentDates: false,
    monthNamesShort: [
        'Gen',
        'Feb',
        'Mar',
        'Apr',
        'Mag',
        'Giu',
        'Lug',
        'Ago',
        'Set',
        'Ott',
        'Nov',
        'Dic',
    ],
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next,today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,listDay',
    },
    buttonText: {
        today: 'Oggi',
        month: 'Mese',
        week: 'Settimana',
        day: 'Giorno',
    },
    events: [],
    selectable: true,
    eventRender: (event, element) => {
        element.html(
            '<div style="padding: 3px; height: 100%;" *ngFor="let event of events"' +
            ' class="c-label-appointment event-state-' + event.attributes.status + ' event-esit-' + event.attributes.esit + '">' +
            '<span class="fc-time">' +
            moment(event.start).format('HH:mm') + '</span>' +
            ' <span class="fc-nomeCliente"><strong>' + event.attributes.customer.name +
            ' ' + event.attributes.customer.surname + '</strong></span>' +
            '</div>',
        );
    },
};
```

And the following code is Html file:

```
        <div class="col col-md-12 calendar-container">
        <div class="panel">
            <div class="panel-body with-padding container-calendar">
                <div class="opacity-black-calendar" *ngIf="isWorking"></div>
                <angular2-fullcalendar id="calendar" [options]=""></angular2-fullcalendar>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I'm using the bootstrap breakpoints (mobile version when max-width < 576).

Comment: I resolved, it was really simple

Comment: If you resolved the error, you can add your fix as an answer.

Comment: It's under the question

Comment: I suggest you add that as an answer to your own question, making it easier for other people to see that the question has been resolved.

Comment: I added the solution under the question, but i don't know how to highlight it.

Comment: There is a blue button at the bottom the page with the text "Answer Your Question".

Comment: Thank you, i didn't see the button

Answer (score 2):

I simply added the following option to calendarOption:

```
 contentHeight: ()=>{
      console.log(screen.width);
      if(screen.width < 577) {
            return 600
        } else {
            return 1000
        }
      },
```

Comment: Works great! All I had to do was tweak the values to my liking.

Answer (score 2):

```
.fc-scroller {height:100% !important;}
```

I want to control via CSS, this is working.